# Docusign Api - Attach Document that does not require signature

Tags: docusignapi

How can I attach a document that has several textTabs to fill out but does not require a signature?

Comment: You want to add that document in the envelope, correct? and not as an attachment?

Comment: There are many examples in SO to use DS API to add a document in an envelope with text tabs, its not mandatory to have a signature tab on a document. Signature Tab is only required when you want a signature from someone on the document.

Comment: Hi @AmitKBist , Please add your answer as a formal answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples in SO to use DS API to add a document in an envelope with text tabs, its not mandatory to have a signature tab on a document. Signature Tab is only required when you want a signature from someone on the document.